# Angular and JSON interaction?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a very basic system involving angular.js and JSON, but I can't get it to behave.  All I want to do is get the value for a particular field in my JSON file and spit it onto the page.  Can anyone see why this isn't working?  It finds the database every time, but I can't seem to access the object.

**HTML & JS**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="ngApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var ngApp = angular.module('ngApp', []);
    ngApp.controller('ngCtrl', function($scope, $http){
        $http.get("db.json").success(function(data){
            console.log("Database found");
            $scope.data = data;
        });
    });
</script>
<body ng-controller="ngCtrl">
    <div>Data goes here: {{data.field1}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JSON**

```
[
    {
        "field1":"data1",
        "field2":"data2"
    }
]
```

I'm very new to angular, so I wouldn't be surprised if there's something I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `json` response is `array` of `objects`. So, you've to use array notation to access the data from it.

See the highlighted changes below:

```
<div>Data goes here: {{data[0].field1}}</div>
//                         ^^^
```

You might want to use [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to loop over all the data

```
<body ng-controller="ngCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">
        <span> Field1 : {{item.field1}}</span>
        <span> Field2 : {{item.field2}}</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

From first look it seems that json data returned is array of an objects. Try this

```
data[0].field1
```